# How to remove duplicate entries from a hash based on a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a  list with duplicate entries . I need a list with unique entries based on unit_id.

```
hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

Expected Output:

```
hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

Comment: Probably it is coming from your nested attributes from. You could fix it there inside the `form_for`.. why this manual work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hash_list.to_a
         .uniq! { |_, v| v['unit_id'] }
         .to_h
```

But note that, the duplicates are removed only based on the key `unit_id`.

To do it based on multiple keys,

```
hash_list.to_a
         .uniq! { |_, v| v.values_at('unit_id','_destroy') }
         .to_h
```

Please have a look at [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

**Output**

```
>> hash_list = { "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"} }
#=> {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
>> hash_list.to_a.uniq! { |_, v| v.values_at('unit_id','_destroy') }.to_h
#=> {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Comment: Nice solution. `uniq!` avoids the creation of another array and is probably a wee bit faster.

Comment: Thanks.  How can i include '_destroy' also to this checking. i have the following list  :                    hash_list = {
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
} and need the result as:    "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"}, "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that does not convert the hash to an array, modify the array, then convert the modified array back to a hash:

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new
hash_list.select { |_,h| s.add?(h["unit_id"]) }
  #=> {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```